# Intermediate value theorem proof of solution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that an equation such as $\frac{c}{x^3+2x^2-1} + \frac{b}{x^3+x-2} = 0$ has
at least one solution in the interval $(-1,1)$? The denominator of the faction
goes to zero when the interval values are substituted and the fraction becomes undefined.

Comment: If the range of a continuous function $f$ over the interval $(-1,1)$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$, there is some $\xi\in(-1,1)$ such that $f(\xi)=0$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

consider the function 
$$y=f(x)=\frac{c}{x^3+2x^2-1} + \frac{b}{x^3+x-2}= \frac{c}{(x+1)(x^2+x+1)} + \frac{b}{(x-1)(x^2+x+2)}$$

for $x\in [-1,1]$we have three critical points for the domain of the function: $x=-1$, $x=1$ and $x=\alpha= \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$: in these points the function does not exists, but on the other points f the interval the function is continue.

testing the limits at these points we have:
$$
\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=-\infty \qquad \lim_{x\to \alpha^-}f(x)=-\infty \qquad \lim_{x\to \alpha^+}f(x)=+\infty \qquad \lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=-\infty \qquad 
$$

so, in the sub-interval $(\alpha,1) \subset [-1,1]$ we are sure that there is a zero of the function by the intermediate value theorem.